# Mobile Flex 4.5 FormItem errorTip not showing

Tags: forms, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-mobile

I'm currently trying to use the numbervalidator to validate that a couple of my fields that are using decimal values. I'd like it appear how the mx examples show e.g. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/validators/NumberValidator.html#includeExamplesSummary

Even though I've enabled it (read below), the errorTip is not appearing. And the error message it does show is placed at the top of the screen rather than within the formitem.

```
<s:NumberValidator id="nv1" allowNegative="false" source="{field1}" property="text" fractionalDigits="3"  />
<s:NumberValidator id="nv2" allowNegative="false" source="{field2}" property="text" fractionalDigits="3"  />
```

I read a suggestion to override the formitem skin and set showErrorTip to true (on the contentGroup) but that had no impact. I also removed errorTextDisplay to try and stop the other error message appearing however that also had no impact.

I'd be happy enough if I could get the existing error messages to appear within the formItem (underneath). I've included the basic structure of my view below:

```
<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:Group>
        <s:Form id="myForm" width="100%">
            <s:layout>
                <s:FormLayout gap="0"/>
            </s:layout>
            <s:HGroup width="100%">
                <s:FormItem label="Field1" width="50%">
                    <s:TextInput id="field1" width="100%" text="{data.field1}" restrict="0-9." />
                </s:FormItem>
                <s:FormItem label="Field2" width="50%">
                    <s:TextInput id="field2" width="100%" text="{data.field2}" restrict="0-9." />
                </s:FormItem>
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:Form>
    </s:Group>
</s:Scroller>
```

It's a very long form (I've left out the other fields) which is why I've used a scroller and I'm showing the inputs in a two column layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the solution to my own question, partially because I neglected to mention what turned out to be an important part of the problem. The default layout of the form skins were pretty terrible so I had switched to the StackedFormSkin and StackedFormItemSkin respectively.

However the Stacked skins move the errorTextDisplay from the formitem to the form skin. What I ended up needing to do was create my own skins (c+p'd from the respective stacked skins).

In my form skins I simply removed the errorTextDisplay element from the FormSkin and copied errorTextDisplay from the original FormItemSkin, made a few alterations (as below) to make it appear underneath the text input.

```
<s:RichText id="errorTextDisplay" includeIn="errorStates"
            fontStyle="italic" fontWeight="normal" color="0xFE0000"
            left="contentCol:0" right="helpCol:10"
            bottom="row3:10" baseline="row3:0" 
            maxDisplayedLines="-1"/>
```

You'll need to add row3 as an extra ConstraintRow.

Basically the change above will get the advantages of the StackedForm skins but means that you're error messages will still appear alongside the input which caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, This should do the trick of showing the error message, U need to add a trigger to the validator and mention what event it has to trigger upon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:NumberValidator id="nv1" allowNegative="false" source="{field1}" property="text" fractionalDigits="3"  
                           trigger="{validate}" triggerEvent="click" requiredFieldError="No use"/>
        <s:NumberValidator id="nv2" allowNegative="false" source="{field2}" property="text" fractionalDigits="3" 
                           trigger="{validate}" triggerEvent="click" requiredFieldError="No use"/>
    </fx:Declarations>


    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Group>
            <s:Form id="myForm" width="100%">
                <s:layout>
                    <s:FormLayout gap="0"/>
                </s:layout>
                <s:VGroup width="100%">
                    <s:FormItem label="Field1" width="50%">
                        <s:TextInput id="field1" width="100%" text="11" restrict="0-9." />
                    </s:FormItem>
                    <s:FormItem label="Field2" width="50%">
                        <s:TextInput id="field2" width="100%" text="22" restrict="0-9." />
                    </s:FormItem>
                </s:VGroup>
                <s:Button id="validate" label="Validate"/>
            </s:Form>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Nope I'm afraid this still doesn't work properly. The error displays (it always has done but in the wrong position). It's like it ignores where the text field is and just sticks it outside of all the elements. The icon appears in the right position but the error messages appear at the top (out of context).

Comment: I continued looking into it and discovered what I had been doing wrong. The StackedForm skins move the errors into the main form object rather than individual items. You're answer helped me to look in the right direction so I have given it an up-vote and posted the full solution below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you were getting differnent type of error with an icon is because you have used `<s:Form>` and `<s:FormItem>`, While changing it to `<mx:Form>` and `<mx:FormItem>` you will get the old kind of error with the highlighted box and error on tool tip. Try the below sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:NumberValidator id="nv1" allowNegative="false" source="{field1}" property="text" fractionalDigits="3"  />
        <s:NumberValidator id="nv2" allowNegative="false" source="{field2}" property="text" fractionalDigits="3"  />
    </fx:Declarations>


    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Group>
            <mx:Form id="myForm" width="100%">
                <s:HGroup width="100%">
                    <mx:FormItem label="Field1" width="50%">
                        <s:TextInput id="field1" width="100%" text="1" restrict="0-9." />
                    </mx:FormItem>
                    <mx:FormItem label="Field2" width="50%">
                        <s:TextInput id="field2" width="100%" text="2" restrict="0-9." />
                    </mx:FormItem>
                </s:HGroup>
            </mx:Form>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: It's not letting me use those elements. It gives the standard "Could not resolve to a component implementation" error. 

I have included the namespace line at the top. I can use other mx elements but the form ones don't appear in the list.

I'm guessing this might be, because of it being a mobile application.

Comment: Ya I tried. They have made <s:Form> as default for Flex mobile projects, because thr s no point in showing an error on mouseover for a text input in a mobile. By default user interface standards, it is best to show the error next to the text input with an icon for a mobile application. All you need to do is minimize the length of your text input and allow space for the error message.